# Pandas read_csv huge file (50gb) issue

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to open a huge csv file (ca. 50gb) through Pandas.read_csv.
I saw other question in which the solution is to use chunks, but it is not a good way for me.
This file contains lot of data (I don't know how many) from '95 to present. Actually, I need to use just the ending rows (eg. from 2010) that probably allow me to read the file.
Many thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Dask`. I just started using this wonderful library as I was running into similar issues. It is very similar to pandas (although a litlle bit limited on all of the functions) but allows you to read in much more data and do a lot of basic functions like merge, groupby, and many more.

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

From the linked documentation above, below is how you would read in a file with dask. It is the same code as pandas.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('2014-*.csv')
df.head()
```